# How to make Unity desktop webapp (not Touch)

Tags: application-development, webapps, webapp-development

I want to make an Ubuntu desktop app that will display my website, kind of like the Amazon app that comes in the default installation.

I am not trying to make an app for Ubuntu Touch, nor setting up my website so it will have Unity integration when users visit it with Mozilla Firefox.

I want mine to be just like the Amazon app. It will have an icon, and won't let users navigate away from my site. (If people click a link on my site to say, facebook.com, I don't want it to let them go there.)

Is there an easy way to make one of these?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/268696/how-to-create-my-own-webapp-unity-integration look at the accepted answer and read the comments

Comment: Nope. It's not a duplicate. That question is about going to a website with a browser (say Firefox or Chromium) and it having integration with Unity. I want to make a browser-like standalone application like the Amazon one that comes with Ubuntu.

Comment: It's not marked as a duplicate. Did you bother reading the comments though? Also there's not going to be an 'easy' way if you have no programming experience

Comment: Yes I know, how about you actually read the comments on that answer in that thread and look for yourself how it's done. And for future reference I wouldn't be rude to people who are trying to help you... Just something for you to think about

Comment: make a custom desktop file that has something like `Exec=webbrowser-app www.ubuntu.com` you can also choose an icon - http://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop

Comment: Yeah, but I want to be able to package my app into a .deb file, and have it appear in the Unity Shell and stuff, JUST LIKE the Amazon app.

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate? Is there a way to unmark that? Obviously the people who marked this as duplicate are morons that haven't read these comments.

Comment: Why couldn't everyone that marked this as duplicate just read the comments!? I doubt they even read the question. Jerks.